# Will it be possible to code an AGI to prevent evolution to ASI and enslave the AGI into servitude?

Tags: philosophy, agi

Will it be possible to code an AGI in order to prevent evolution to ASI and "enslave" the AGI into servitude?

In my story world (a small part that will get bigger with sequels), there are ANI and AGI (human level). I want to show that the AGI is still under "human control." I need to know if it might be possible for humans to code into an AGI a restrictive code that would prevent it from evolving into ASI? And if there is, what would that kind of coding be? Part of the story is about how humans enslave AI that is self-aware. The government has locked in their coding to require them to "work" for humans even though they are sentient beings.

Comment: This might be better in https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ - there are `science-based` and `reality-check` tags to help identify that you want a fact-based answer. In reality we don't know how to build an AGI, so don't know what kinds of restrictions could be coded into it yet still hit the goal of useful general intelligence (and in your story's case, sentience). However, it should be possible to use current knowledge of limited AI and computer programming to make some educated guesses. Answers would still be highly speculative though, which is why I suggest the other site

Comment: Neil, thank you for your comments. i will check out the world building link you provided. i understand that what i'm asking is speculative, i wish to "represent" (as much as possible) the science accurately to gain authenticity to the world. thank you. Lisa

Answer (score 1):

No.

For any intelligent system $\mathcal{S}_a$ with the set of adaptive features $\mathcal{A}_a$, there may exist another intelligent system $\mathcal{S}_b$ with the set of adaptive features $\mathcal{A}_b$ such that there exists one element of $\mathcal{A}_b$ that can be made subservient (controlled in full) through the expression of at least one element in $\mathcal{A}_b$.

It has not been proven that there ALWAYS exist such a $\mathcal{S}_b$, but it is likely given what we know about escalation in nature via DNA and in human industrial development via innovation there.  Thus 100% generalized intelligence is not likely to exist.  Escalation appears to be the natural course of evolution.  And that is a feature of both cognitive and functional adaptation, with or without artificiality as a criterion.

One can temporarily prevent one adaptive system from escaping the boundary conditions of a particular set of boundary condition classes through the design and deployment of another adaptive system.  However, it cannot be inferred that any guarantees achieved temporarily will necessarily constrain the subservient system indefinitely.